# Why is go app running as several processes?

Tags: linux, go, process, operating-system

I have a very simple program written in go:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("good bye")
}
```

Now I'm building it using "go build .". When I look at htop to see the application running, it shows me that several processes are being executed on my machine.

[image: htop output]

Can someone explain to me why is that happening? I would expect a single goroutine program to run as single process.

Comment: i think that for example the garbage collector runs in its own thread

Comment: It does run a single process, but it runs multiple threads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why is that happening?

Yes. You are either using htop or top with H which shows threads. Your program uses several threads like any Go program (see also Pizza lord's comment).